# PM2 Process Manager is not showing the actual version from each project package.json version but NVM version number

Tags: node.js, pm2, nvm

[image]

I'm running PM2 list on MacOS, and those projects node are running of the `nvm` managed node version. by right the expectation on the `versioning` column it should be showing individual node process version based on their package.json version number respectively.

but it's showing the version of `nvm` (node version manager). which is odd. Anyone has a clue or is this a bug from PM2 ? It happens for the couple of teammate who are working on MacOS either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally understand the logic how `pm2` works.
the current setup node was managed by `nvm` and `pm2` is installed globally inside the node version.

when those process above was started by using the following style:

```
{
    ...
    script: 'npm',
    args: 'run start:auth'
    ...
}
```

in the pm2 config.js (start script), it indirectly ask PM2 to refer to the nvm folder, to use the `npm` there. at such when we inspect the process by invoking `pm2 info auth` it shows this line, this gave us the hint, pm2 would read the `package.json` resides in the `~/.nvm` folder, thus it becomes the version from nvm. [image]

Therefore the mystery is **resolved**.

**NOTE:** PM2 would read the first available `package.json` from the `repository root`, or somewhere available within the `script path` (e.g. when we do the `pm2 info <process>`). with that said, in normal circumstance we only use pm2 in a production environment, and we tend to use it to start the actual *.js script, and it would process the package.json correctly without any issues.